# Changing Form's Icon in Visual Studio 2012 C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, icons

I am trying to change the icon of the form (top left) and any other place I see little squares default icon.

I have tried:

- Clicking the form, go to "Window Style" and changing the Icon to the .ico file I have on my computer - this shows as if it actually changes - but whenever I debug or publish - it is still the original default Icon.
- Going to Project's properties- Resources - adding the Icon as Resource - back to Application under Properties - change "Icon and Manifest" to the resourced Icon. It shows the new Icon next to the browse button - but nothing changes in the actual program.

**Note** at first the Background Image I had selected for the form wasn't applying either - I would change it via the form - Properties - Appearance - BackgroundImage - Select from computer. Would show as changed but as soon as I would debug or publish or would not be there.
-Added it to my resources and then chose it from the BackgroundImage browse - chose it from project resources and then it worked.

Comment: Is this a WinForms application?

Comment: Yes, it is the Icon property of the form.  Go back to your icon editor and add an icon with a simple format, 16 x 16 and no more than 256 colors.  The Windows version you use matters a great deal.

Comment: @HansPassant Tried as you suggested - the icon looked really crappy after the edit - and there was no change. Still the default icon after clicking debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:
With the idea that my Background image wasn't working until I had it in the Resources. I went to the Form1_load event and added the following code:

```
System.Drawing.Icon ico = Properties.Resources.Untitled;
this.Icon = ico;
```

As "Properties.Resources.Untitled" being my icon that I added to my Resources.

And now seems to be workings as wanted.

Comment: You can just add `this.Icon = global::MyNameSpace.Properties.Resources.MyIcon;` in the `InitializeComponent` function in the .Designer.cs sub-file, though. No need for the load event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the icon on every form as well using the Icon property of the Form.

Comment: Only have the 1 form. So what now?

Comment: @user1777906 He means: from Form1 design window, go to properties. Select `Icon` and browse for your image.

Comment: Yea I know, but in my question I had said I had already done that - and since I only have one form - I have no others to apply what he said.